# How can I get layer values and layer name from pdf, and sub-layers?

Tags: java, itext7

[Here are my test pdf file.](https://github.com/dwp73/img/blob/main/bslf.pdf)

[image: pdf layer and sub-layers]
[image: I need those values(like x, y, width, height).]

By use this code, I can get layer name, but can not get sub-layers name.

```
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
        List<PdfLayer> layers = pdfDoc
                .getCatalog()
                .getOCProperties(true)
                .getLayers();

        for (PdfLayer layer : layers) {
            if (layer.isOnPanel()) {
                PdfObject layerName = layer.getPdfObject().get(PdfName.Name);
                List<PdfLayer> subLayers = layer.getChildren();

                System.out.println(layerName.toString());
                System.out.println(layer.getPdfObject());
            }
        }
```

I can get `main_layer` by this code. But can't get sub-layers name, like `sub_layer_1`, `sub_layer_19`.

And I don't know how to get curse value by itext7.

For python, I can use pdfplumber get curse, line, char, rect info.

How can I get those by itext7 ?

Comment: Please share the example PDF to test. Furthermore, what *curse, line, char, rect info* are you talking about? Layers (or more exactly _optional content groups_) neither are lines, characters, or rectangles nor are they superstitious.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your notice, I'm upload my test pdf. And actually, I just want to read layer and sub-layers, get values(like x, y), and layer name.

Comment: *"get values(like x, y)"* - *x, y* of what? Optional content groups don't have coordinates. Do you mean the position of each item related to an ocg? Or a binding box of all of them? Please explain.

Comment: Yes, I need the position of each item related to an ocg.

Comment: As far as I can see there are no optional content groups in your example PDF https://github.com/dwp73/img/blob/main/bslf.pdf at all. Or are you not talking about layers as Adobe sees them (i.e. optional content groups from the PDF standard) but something proprietary structures? I do see some proprietary elements in your example, in particular related to some HDAG tools.

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance. I can not figure out what's difference between  “optional content groups” and Layers from Adobe Illustrator(in my [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20AyE.png), I need layer "234", and sub-layers  "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"...). I need those layer's name, and positions(like x, y, width, height).

Comment: new [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvPkX.png), I need layer "main_layer", and sub_layers "sub_layer_1", "sub_layer_2"...

Comment: Your screenshot is from Illustrator and you want to fetch the names of the sublayers from PDF created by a third party. Obviously to fetch the names of the sublayers from a PDF, they must have been added there in the first place. Having that said, I don't see any sublayers with names like `sub_layer_N` in the PDF - I can only see two layers: `2_layer` and `main_layer` - both by using a PDF viewer tool and by inspecting an internal PDF structure. So the layers you are looking for are just not there and your code is fine